# Rails magento API with savon - complex filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, magento

I am trying to import orders from a Magento store to a rails app using Savon and Magento API. So far here is my code:

```
require 'savon'

client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://mywebsite.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl")

session_id = client.call(:login,
  message: {
    username: "myapiuser",
    api_key: "myapipassword"
  }).body[:login_response][:login_return]

orders = client.call(:sales_order_list,
  message: {
    session_id: session_id, complex_filters: [{
        key: "created_at", operator: "gt", value: '2014-10-14 00:00:00' }]
  })
```

I need to use a complex filter to find orders created after a certain date. The reason for this is if I try to pull all the orders at once it overloads the server. I tried using the complex filter above, but it still tries to pull all the orders. Am I passing the filter in an improper way? Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution? I’m at the same problem but don’t get anything out of Magento using complex filters.